# Bad practice to name variable to class or id?

Tags: javascript

Is it bad practice to name a variable to the same name of a class or id? If so, why?

**For instance:**
`var slideshowSlides = document.getElementsByClassName("slideshowSlides");`

Comment: This question is either too broad, **opinion based** or requires discussion and so is off-topic for Stack Overflow. If you have a specific, answerable, programming issue, please provide full details.

Comment: @Paulie_D Thank you for the answer. I thought there was a standard, that I couldn't find.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if I am making a opinion here. But ideally if possible all your names of related things should match as much as possible. hence, above is always a good practice. `id` is unique on a html page and hence should be the preferred way so that you can map unique elements with the variables.

Hence, more neater is to use id:

> var slideshowSlides = document.getElementById("slideshowSlides");

Comment: Thank you for the personal opinion, I really appreciate the feedback. Your answer sounds logic.